# How to slim the thick fonts in Imagemagik

Tags: cmd.exe, imagemagick, tiff

I was trying to slim down the thick fonts[thick image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRuxd.png) to "3033 Elgin Avenue" something as keyed here.
Any suggestion.

Comment: Use a font editor

Comment: HI, Iam looking to be part of imagemagick process, as i have included other parameters, like grayscale, filter etc